# How should I use CompletableFuture for void method in springboot async

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future

How should I use CompletableFuture for void method in springboot async. Explanation with examples will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example:

```
  @Async
  public CompletableFuture<Void> foo()  {
       // Do some work
       return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
  }
```

Comment: How will exception handling work in this case? Spring mentions `void` as requiring special configuration, but doesn't mention `CompletableFuture<Void>`.

Comment: What do you want to know about exception handling?

Comment: `@Async` methods which return `void` require some configuration setup via `AsyncConfigurer` and `AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler`. So I'm wondering: what about this "hack" where you return a `CompletableFuture<Void>` via `return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);` (which in fact means you will not be able to ever block to make sure that the code has completed)? Would it be possible to have it throw an Exception into the thread which called `foo()` when something went wrong?

Comment: Why is this a hack? This just works as it is. And no you can't throw exceptions that will be caught in the main thread

Comment: Wouldn't `@Async  public void foo()  { /* Do some work */ }` work as well? Why is there a need for `CompletableFuture<Void>` and `return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);` ?

Comment: To wait for the result

Comment: But `completedFuture` says this: "`Returns a new CompletableFuture that is already completed with the given value.`" I don't think any waiting would happen?

Comment: Ah now I see what you mean! I'm sorry yes you are completely right!